# socket.makefile issues in python 3 while creating a http proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, makefile

```
from socket import *
import sys

# Create a server socket, bind it to a port and start listening
tcpSerSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverPort = 12000
tcpSerSock.bind(('', serverPort))
tcpSerSock.listen(1)
print ("Server ready")

while 1==1:
  # Start receiving data from the client. e.g. request = "GET http://localhost:portNum/www.google.com" 
  tcpCliSock, addr = tcpSerSock.accept()
  print ('Received a connection from:', addr)
  request = str(tcpCliSock.recv(1024).decode())
  print ("Requested " + request)
  # Extract the file name from the given request
  fileName = request.split()[1]
  print ("File name is " + fileName)

  fileExist = "false"
  fileToUse = "/" + fileName

  print ("File to use: " + fileToUse)
  try:
    # Check wether the file exist in the cache. The open will fail and go to "except" in case the file doesn't exist. Similar to try/catch in java
    f = open(fileToUse[1:], "r")                      
    outputData = f.readlines()                        
    fileExist = "true"
    # ProxyServer finds a cache hit and generates a response message
    tcpCliSock.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n")            
    tcpCliSock.send("Content-Type:text/html\r\n")
    tcpCliSock.send(outputData)
    print ('This was read from cache')     

  except IOError:
    if fileExist == "false": 
        # Create a socket on the proxyserver
        c = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        hostn = fileName.replace("www.","",1) #max arg specified to 1 in case the webpage contains "www." other than the usual one          
        print (hostn)                                   
        try:
            # Connect to the socket to port 80
            c.bind(('', 80))
            # Create a temporary file on this socket and ask port 80 for the file requested by the client
            print("premake")

            fileObj = c.makefile('r', 0)

            print("postmake")
            fileObj.write("GET " + "http://" + fileName + " HTTP/1.1\r\n")  
            # Read the response into buffer
            print("post write")
            buff = fileObj.readlines()
            # Create a new file in the cache for the requested file. 
            tmpFile = open("./" + filename,"wb")
            # Send the response in the buffer to both client socket and the corresponding file in the cache
            for line in buff:
                tmpFile.write(line)
            tcpCliSock.send(tmpFile)  

        except:
            print ("Illegal request")
            break                                               
    else:
        # HTTP response message for file not found
        print("HTTP response Not found")

# Close the client and the server sockets    
tcpCliSock.close()
#tcpSerSock.close()
```

The code never manages to execute the 'try' entered in 'except IOError'. The problem seems to be the socket.makefile(mode, buffsize) function, which has poor documentation for python 3. I tried passing 'rwb', 'r+', 'r+b' and so on to the function, but at most I would manage to create the file and be unable to write to it thereafter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a python2.7 vs python3 issue. While `makefile('r',0)` works in python 2.7, you need `makefile('r',None)` in python3.

From the documentation for python2.7:
`socket.makefile([mode[, bufsize]])`

From the documentation for python3:
`socket.makefile(mode='r', buffering=None, *, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None)`

Comment: Also python3 supports send() and recv() functions for socket programming which handles the buffer files internally. So, you can also get rid of fileObj altogether. (Double check on this one though.)

Comment: Thanks! python does not seem to provide a particularly good environment for socket/network programming :)